# Installing Bootstrap 4 on ember js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I've looked around but can't find the proper way to include bootstrap with ember. I don't want the `ember-bootstrap` package since it doesn't support `bootstrap 4`.

I'm also lost about every article outhere telling to use bower to install it but since bower is being remplaced with yarn I don't want to use a deprecated method.

I've try many times but it always fail when I'm trying to import the bootstrap.js file in my `ember-cli-build.js` like so -->
`app.import('bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js');` 
I'm having this error

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliMergeTrees: TreeMerger (vendor & appJS)] 
failed with:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/private/tmp/my-first-
ember-app/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-
S9AGEQc7.tmp/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-
official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js'
```

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6` for bootstrap and import the required files through `ember-cli-build.js` file from `node_modules` folder.

For importing node_modules file, you should have [ember-cli version 2.15](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v2.15.0) onwards.

Comment: Thanks it went just well after upgrading ember !

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong assumption in your question. ember-bootstrap does support Bootstrap 4 since version 1.0.0-alpha.5 which was released on February 27th 2017. There is a section in [setup guide](http://www.ember-bootstrap.com/#/getting-started/setup) about how to switch to Bootstrap 4.

In short it's:

- `ember install ember-bootstrap`
- `ember generate ember-bootstrap --bootstrap-version=4`

ember-bootstrap 1.0.0 is not released yet. Current version is 1.0.0-rc.4. Also Bootstrap 4 support is [only experimental](http://www.ember-bootstrap.com/#/getting-started/bootstrap-4). But that's mainly caused by Bootstrap 4 not having a stable release yet.

If you don't like or don't need the component of ember-bootstrap you are better of with just importing bootstrap assets as described by kumkanillam.

Comment: My mistake i've just RTFM lol and as you said it does support bootstrap 4 ! Thanks